# Link no longer working in profile "About Me"?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

Just now, I tried to add a link to my SO profile "About Me" (to the last line, to be clear). But it's not working, i.e. only show the text without the link.

I have tried the following two ways:

1. Link directly after the text:

   ```
   [Rename and move files in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049845/2589776)
   ```
2. Put links together associated with numbers:

   ```
   [Rename and move files in batch][1]
   ...
   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049845/2589776
   ```

**P.S.:** Links that I added before by using either method #1 or #2 are working well. But not any more for new added links.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: `status-nonrepro` here. Can you paste the exact markup that you used? (A short reproducible would suffice)

Comment: It's working well or not.Please be clear.

Comment: works for me http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158100/rene

Comment: @AmalMurali I have replaced it with real links. Please check.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's now working now, but working before. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not working for me. :(

Comment: I verified in the formatting sandbox and your markup works. Are you sure there are no javascript errors in your browser?

Comment: @rene All other links works well. So it's probably not because of the java-script errors.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Can you update your Meta profile just for a moment to test this?

Comment: @AmalMurali I just tested it, still not working. :(

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Tested what? I'm sorry but "*Not working*" isn't really helpful.

Comment: `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049845/2589776">hero</a>`

Comment: @AmalMurali I tried to add another link, but still only showing the text without the link.

Comment: Add http:// otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Can you delete everything else for a moment? The first link seems to work. Something tells me you have something wrong with your formatting there.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried this method, it's still not working for this new link, but **somehow** make the link before it start to work. Even weird though. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flair link was... weird.

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/1238452/herohuyongtao">![profile for herohuyongtao on Stack Exchange][1]


  [1]: http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1238452.png
```

Was that the old (deprecated) style?

I updated it to the new style specified on the [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) page and all of your links are now working.

This also fixed the issue where the first couple of lines of plain text (the quotes) in your profile had been linking back to your SE profile.

Comment: Yeah, it works now. :P But how does the old flair link affect the other links? And why doesn't it affect others before?

Comment: @herohuyongtao I honestly have no idea. I just noticed that your first few lines of text were rendering as links when they shouldn't, so I deleted your flair block to see if that's what was causing it.

Comment: By the way, you have the right to see the source code? :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yes, moderators can see/edit anything in your profile. It's hardly ever used, but comes in handy once in a while.

Comment: @Bill I feel old, can you edit my age to be 20 again? ;)